# Variable pricing at different quantity levels

Tags: price, quantity

This is a feature I saw one a competitors non-magento site and I'd love to see something like it on our magento site.

We sell items by the singles, in a full case and in multiple cases. We offer quantity discounts at each level.

For a single, the price on an item might be $1.00 each. If you buy a full case of 50 units, the price might drop to $0.80 each. If you buy 10 full cases (500 units total), the price might drop to $0.70. What we'd like to see is a rational split at each level that, if the customer wants to buy more than that, they are charged multiple prices.

For instance, if they wanted to buy 55 of the units above. Instead of being charged $0.80 x 55 units, we want them to be charged the 50 unit price (one full case) for the first 50 units and then the per unit price on the other pieces, so it would be 50 x $0.80 = $400 + 5 x$1.00 = $5 for a total of $405.00. In this case, let's say they wanted to buy 560 units. They would pay for the 500 units at $0.70 each, then the 50 units at $0.80 each then the last 10 units at $1.00 each. This would output in the cart with all 3 prices shown.

I've attached a screenshot of how this is done by our competitor. Is there an existing plugin/extension that does this? If not, who should we talk to about creating one?

thanks!

[image]